# firefox memory leak when adding Video tags dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, memory-leaks, html5-video

It seems when I play my solution in firefox the "heap unallocated" keeps growing as I dynamically replace objects/video tags.

```
$( buffer ).empty();
$( buffer ).html( '<object id="' + id + '" name="' + id + '" width="1366" height="768" data="displayQueue[ position ].filename + '" ></object>' );
```

So basically I am creating a carousel which replaces what is in the buffer so that different videos/flash content are played one after another in a loop.

But I am finding that firefox is growing 20Mb each time a tag is replaced until firefox runs out of memory to allocate and crashes (the process is using 2gb or more).

Is firefox caching the content and not recognizing that I am reloading the same content (i have run firefox in private mode but still does the same thing?

Also I figure this is probably a bad solution, I would be extremely grateful if you can suggest a more elegant solution.

EDIT:

Upon further debugging I have found that this only seems to occur when I load a video tag firefox keeps it in memory even after I have removed it and run the jquery .empty method.

```
$( buffer ).html( '<video id="' + id + '" width="1366" height="768" src="displayQueue[ position ].filename + '"></video>' );
```

Comment: Have you compared against using normal DOM methods to remove and then reinsert the element?

Comment: Reuse the object, replace the data.

Comment: Does the memory get released if you replace the tab with `about:memory` and minimise memory usage? Either way you should probably file a bug in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: I tried using innerHTML and setting it to '' but does not effect the problem. Is there another DOM method I could try?

Comment: try to cache jquery object instead of matching it before every `.html()` call, i.e. `$buffer = $(buffer)` and then call all methods on `$buffer` like `$buffer.html()`, `$buffer.empty()`

Comment: I have changed it to cache jquery object but still it is growing. But I will keep this as It does reduce the number of times jquery has to look for the DOM element.

Comment: If i replace the tab with about memory, the heap unclassified will empty itself out. So basically As soon as I close the tab/window firefox will return to a reasonable memory usage.